# react-rails gem pass hash in view helper react_component

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I use the react-rails gem and have trouble with passing a hash to the react_component view helper:

How does the equivalent of

```
React.render(<BookApp books={BOOKS} />, document.getElementById('react-container'));
```

looks like?

I assumed

```
<div id="react-container">
  <%= react_component('BookApp', books: '{BOOKS}') %>
</div>
```

But this approach doesn't pass the hash values as props.
What am i missing?

in books.js.jsx

```
var BOOKS = {
  ulysses: {
    slug: 'ulysses',
    title: 'Ulysses',
    body: 'YES BECAUSE HE NEVER DID...'
  },
  seizeTheDay: {
    slug: 'seizeTheDay',
    title: 'Seize the Day',
    body: 'Seize the Day, first published in 1956...'
  }
};

var CollapsibleBlock = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    return(
      <div className=
        {this.props.toggleState ? 'open' :
                                  'closed'}>
        <h3 onClick=
          {this.props
               .toggleHandler
               .bind(null, this.props.book.slug)}> // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slug' of undefined
        </h3>
        <p>{this.props.book.body}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var BookApp = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      ulysses: true,
      seizeTheDay: false
    }
  },
// code omitted

render: function() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Toggable Content</h1>
        <button onClick={this.toggleAll}>Toggle all</button> {}
        <div>
          {this.toggableBooks(this.props.books)}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

In CollapsibleBlock I get the error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slug' of undefined

I presume it's caused of the empty Books-Hash that is not passed in react_component call on the view page.

Comment: What is it rendering?

Comment: It doesn't render anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to give the React component the *name* of a JavaScript constant, right?

So how about passing the name as a string:

```
<div id="react-container">
  <%= react_component('BookApp', books_name: 'BOOKS') %>
</div>
```

Then, in the component, use the string to lookup a constant from `window`:

```
var BookApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    // Look up BOOKS by name: 
    var books = window[this.props.books_name]
    // store the object as this.state.books
    return {
      ulysses: true,
      seizeTheDay: false,
      books: books,
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<div id="react-container">
  <%= react_component('BookApp', booksJSON: @books.to_json) %>
</div>
```

and in the component:

```
getInitialState: function () {
  return {
    books: (this.props.booksJSON.length > 0 ? JSON.parse(this.props.booksJSON) : []),
  }
  ...
}
```